# Why is this implying a normal vector field?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-fields, exterior-algebra

Suppose $\omega$ is a $n-1$ form on a $n-1$ dimensional manifold and $(a_1(x)dx_1 + ... + a_n(x)dx_n )\wedge \omega = c\Omega $, with $c \neq 0$ and $\Omega =dx_1\wedge...\wedge dx_n$.  Moreover $(a_1(x),...,a_n(x))= a(x)$ is a normal vector on the manifold, with a nonzero norm.  Apparently with this you can say there exists a normal unit vector field on $M$, where you say $n(x) = \frac{a(x)}{\| a(x)| }$ if $c >0$ and $n(x) = -\frac{a(x)}{\| a(x)| }$ if $c < 0$.  Why can you say this, how is from the wedge product seen that the normal vector fields is smooth, as in it "doesn't keep switching" .

Comment: Is the manifold embedded in $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: Yeeah it is in Rn

Comment: And is $a_1(x)dx_1 + \cdots + a_n(x)dx_n$ defined on the manifold or on the whole $\Bbb R^n$?